# Anycubic Chiron homing issue

Tags: bed-leveling, homing, anycubic-chiron

The Anycubic Chiron is the third 3D printer I’ve owned, so I’m fairly familiar with the inner workings of them.

The problem occurs when I home the Z-axis. Once the Z-axis sensor gets triggered, the Z-axis motors should stop. However, Instead of stopping, the Z-axis motors go 2-3  mm further after the Z-axis sensor is already triggered. Therefore, the nozzle of the printer is lower than the bed itself. I've had this printer for 2 years, but the problem started last week.

In the video, you can see that the little red light shuts off when the sensor is triggered. You can also hear the motors spin slightly faster after they’re supposed to stop. If you have any ideas to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the [video link](https://streamable.com/l705ja).

Comment: Hi Christian, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please [edit] your question to add information on how this happened. Is this brand new out-of-the-box behavior, occurring after a while, after a firmware change, suddenly occurred, etc. Please shed some light on the history of the problem.